# Convert Binary Id Field to Text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need the text (representation) of a id field in SQL Server 2005. Is there a way, we can generate the textual representation of the id field?

For instance, if the id field reads as 0x00000000000002F0, I need the text value of 0x00000000000002F0 so that I can run SUBSTR operations on the same.

Constraints

1. I am not allowed to create a stored procedure in the Database (as creation of SP is not allowed)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the datatype of the ID field?

Comment: How are you going to encode the binary to text? Is it ASCII, Unicode, UTF8 etc? What is it you're ultimately trying to do?

Comment: PaulG: Encode the text to Unicode. Basically, we are trying to store this value in another field so that we can eventually do a text matching.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert unicode strings to binary using

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(40),N'Hello World')
(returns 0x480065006C006C006F00200057006F0072006C006400)
```

Convert from binary back to unicode using

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), 0x480065006C006C006F00200057006F0072006C006400)
(returns 'Hello World')
```

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it's not immediately obvious to me why you would want to do this for comparison purposes (as opposed to matching binary values), the undocumented function `sys.fn_varbintohexstr` should do the trick

```
declare  @vb binary(8)
        ,@vc varchar(20)

set @vb = 0x00000000000002F0
set @vc = sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@vb)

--prove that this works by concatenating a string to the varchar value
select @vb, '#' + @vc
```